# SQL Query to remove cyclic redundancy

Tags: sql, oracle, sankey-diagram

I have a table that looks like this:

```
  Column A   |    Column   B    |     Counter
---------------------------------------------
      A      |       B          |       53
      B      |       C          |       23
      A      |       D          |       11
      C      |       B          |       22
```

I need to remove the last row because it's cyclic to the second row.  Can't seem to figure out how to do it.

**EDIT**

There is an indexed date field. This is for Sankey diagram. The data in the sample table is actually the result of a query. The underlying table has:

```
date   | source node | target node | path count
```

The query to build the table is:

```
SELECT source_node, target_node, COUNT(1) 
FROM sankey_table 
WHERE TO_CHAR(data_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')='2013-08-19' 
GROUP BY source_node, target_node
```

In the sample, the last row C to B is going backwards and I need to ignore it or the Sankey won't display. I need to only show forward path.

Comment: How do you know which row to remove, why not remove the 2nd row instead? unless you include a `order by` the database has no real concept of "last row" (ok, if the table is indexed it will likely always return the rows in order of the index but I would be hesitant to rely on that without doing a `order by` on the index columns)

Comment: The rows happen to be ordered accordingly.  I can ignore the second instance.

Comment: Ordered accordingly by what? You can't rely on the order they were add

Comment: Ordered by what, you can't rely on insert order. If you don't explicitly set an order, the DBMS will choose what ever is convenient for it.

Comment: There is an indexed date field.  This is for Sankey diagram.  The data in the sample table is actually the result of a query.  The underlying table has:

date  |  source node |  target node  |  path count

The query to build the table is:
SELECT 
source_node, target_node, COUNT(1) 
FROM sankey_table 
WHERE TO_CHAR(data_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')='2013-08-19'
GROUP BY source_node, target_node

In the sample, the last row C to B is going backwards and I need to ignore it or the Sankey won't display.  I need to only show forward path.

Comment: You're missing the point. How do you determine which way is 'forward' - why is it `B->C` and not `C->B`? All you seem to have are two rows which have target and source both ways around, and no obvious way to decide between them. It isn't clear if you want to use the date order (assuming they have different times recorded), or to pick one arbitrarily, or something else?

Comment: Yes I want to use the date order.  The first one is the correct one. Users select the status manually.  It shouldn't have been done that way but often they select the wrong one.  Like if an order is in "working" status it'll suddenly go to "new."  The date has a timestamp which I use to tell the "valid" state.

Comment: But the date field os not available in this table, only in the original table that was used to populate this one, right? Do you have access to that as well, and can you query against that instead; or can you adjust the process that populates the new table?

Comment: I can query against the original table. I've implemented procedures to adjust the process as well but still not perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can adjust how your table is populated, you can change the query you're using to only retrieve the values for the first direction (for that date) in the first place, with a little bit an analytic manipulation:

```
SELECT source_node, target_node, counter FROM (
  SELECT source_node,
    target_node,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY source_node, target_node) AS counter,
    RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY GREATEST(source_node, target_node),
      LEAST(source_node, target_node), TRUNC(data_date)
        ORDER BY data_date) AS rnk
  FROM sankey_table 
  WHERE TO_CHAR(data_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')='2013-08-19' 
)
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

The inner query gets the same data you collect now but adds a ranking column, which will be 1 for the first row for any source/target pair in any order for a given day. The outer query then just ignores everything else.

This might be a candidate for a materialised view if you're truncating and repopulating it daily.

If you can't change your intermediate table but can still see the underlying table you could join back to it using the same kind of idea; assuming the table you're querying from is called `sankey_agg_table`:

```
SELECT sat.source_node, sat.target_node, sat.counter
FROM sankey_agg_table sat
JOIN (SELECT source_node, target_node,
    RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY GREATEST(source_node, target_node),
      LEAST(source_node, target_node), TRUNC(data_date)
        ORDER BY data_date) AS rnk
  FROM sankey_table) st
ON st.source_node = sat.source_node
AND st.target_node = sat.target_node
AND st.rnk = 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle demos](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73525/4).

Answer (score 1):

Removing all edges from your graph where the tuple (source_node, target_node) is not ordered alphabetically and the symmetric row exists should give you what you want:

```
DELETE 
FROM sankey_table t1
WHERE source_node > target_node
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL from sankey_table t2
  WHERE t2.source_node = t1.target_node
    AND t2.target_node = t1.source_node)
```

If you don't want to DELETE them, just use this WHERE clause in your query for generating the input for the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM yourTable
where [Column A]='C'
```

given that these are all your rows

EDIT

I would recommend that you clean up your source data if you can, i.e. delete the rows that you call backwards, if those rows are incorrect as you state in your comments.

Comment: It must be early!  I totally didn't think of deleting the rows because I really don't need them but this isn't going to do what I need.

Comment: then you must clarify what you need